# I need solution for jquery ajax autocomplete in php

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have used jquery for javascript in my project I need to create autocomplete with php ajax

I am using below code

```
$("input#txtaddkey").autocomplete({
   source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
  });
```

And I have taken some code as below

```
$("input#txtaddkey").autocomplete({
   url: 'keyword.php',
     width: 300,
     max: 10,
     delay: 100,
     cacheLength: 1,
     scroll: false,
     highlight: false
  });
```

But I am not understand how above code will work and How to get the query string from php file.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you see at the [Autocomplete page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote).

Basically your server response (the result in the keyword.php need to be formatted as JSON. i.e.

```
[ { "id": 1, "label": "text 1", "value": "val 1" }, { "id": 2, "label": "text2", "value": "val 2" } ]
```

Check also [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: my question about suppose user search for London on typing "L" i need to get "L" in php query string in php dont know the query string variable

Comment: @ Nik my code is returning as [{"id":"2","keyword":"Games","averageprice":"0.10"},{"id":"3","keyword":"Goa","averageprice":"0.10"}] But in dropdown i am not getting any value li tag print empty

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer..

Query string will pass as  $_GET['term'].

A request object, with a single property called "term", which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, when the user entered "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo".

Thanks every one.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete